# Changing ItemsPresenter in custom ComboBox style to display items next to each other

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I want *ComboBox* to contain Images as items (they will be added programatically). In default *ComboBox* they are displayed vertically. I would like to have them to be displayed like in **VariableSizedWrapGrid** but I'm not exactly sure how to do it.
I have this *ItemsPresenter* for *ComboBox* style but changing it to anything else results in nothing being displayed.

Or maybe I should make it other way (using ListView?). I want selected item to be displayed like in *ComboBox* and after click all items displayed at once (around 25).

How it looks now:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the `ItemsPanel` property:

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
</ComboBox>
```

If you want to use something like `VariableSizedWrapGrid` you can create your own implementation or check out other peoples work for example: [VariableSizedWrapGrid for WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/995465/VariableSizedWrapGrid-for-WPF).

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work (Yes, I've changed Orientation to "Horizontal"). I wonder if it is caused because ComboBox is using UserControl and inside it ItemsPresenter.

Answer (score 0):

I've made some research and it seems it's not possible to achieve what I want. I'll just do it another way to get what I want (*Button* with *Flyout* and *ListView* inside it should do the work).